# How to compare 2 textures of SKSpritenodes

Tags: ios, swift, comparison, textures, sktexture

I am trying to check at a collision if the texture of bodyAA is named "playerpc". If it is, I want to run an action, but I can't figure out how to check.

The code i am using right now:

```
              var testnode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerpc")
              print(testnode.texture)
              if bodyAA.texture == testnode.texture{
                  print("Yes the same")
              }
              else{
                  print(bodyAA.texture)
              }
```

This is the outcome from the console:

```
Optional(<SKTexture> 'playerpc' (153 x 274))
Optional(<SKTexture> 'playerpc' (153 x 274))
```

So it should be the same! but when it compares, my code decides it is not the same, how can I fix this?

Comment: because you have to point what are you comparing in textures, because it has it's own properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`texture` is optional `SKTexture`. So to compare you should unwrap it, and check according to the description like this:

```
if bodyAA.texture!.description == testnode.texture!.description{
                  print("Yes the same")
              }
              else{
                  print(bodyAA.texture)
              }
```

Comment: I like this and use it in my code. Since the textures differ in size depending on whether you use a non-retina, a 2x or a 3x device and I have to make a comparison to a hardcoded texture name, I make the comparison with `if bodyAA.texture!.description.hasPrefix(" ... ") {`